# Слишком длинная подсказка в поле описания правки

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, правки

При редактировании любого сообщения внизу появляется блок для ввода описания правки:

> [image: описание правки]

Можно заменить, что текст подсказки в текущим виде не помещается (всего лишь закрывающая скобка не влезла). Его следует изменить.

Оригинальная строка выглядит так:

> [briefly explain your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting)](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264896?key=da8686ebf725c3ba1ee12da64d260e87)

Текущий перевод (74 символа):

> кратко опишите изменения (исправление ошибок в орфографии, форматировании)

Есть ещё похожая строка с припиской `etc`:

> [briefly explain your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting, etc.)](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/66246523?key=c3462928201014ef85189ebe363a8cb9)

Текущий перевод:

> кратко опишите изменения (исправление ошибок в орфографии, форматировании, и т. д.)

Где она используется, не очень понятно.

Comment: Вы же модер по локализации, меняйте сами :)

Comment: @Other даже предложений не будет?

Comment: Как по мне, то тут всё сказано словом "Описание". В `placeholder` можно написать... "Описание здесь писать".

Comment: Судя по ответам тут не хватает метки [tag:соревнование] или [tag:golf]

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [угу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4698/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8/4705#comment16736_4705)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вместо примера добавим подробное руководство

#### 43 символа

> кратко опишите содержание и смысл изменений

Содержание и так видно по diff-у. А вот смысл изменений не всегда понятен, особенно когда исправляется код или терминология.

Comment: Я утвердил этот перевод на transifex.

Answer (score 4):

#### 65 символов

> кратко опишите изменения (орфография, пунктуация, форматирование)

Участники до 2000 должны выполнять эту инструкцию, поэтому желательно сохранить повелительное наклонение.

Заимствовал у alexolut про пунктуацию. Можно впихнуть ещё что-нибудь полезное на 7 символов.

Comment: Тоже думал о таком варианте. Имеется в виду простое перечисление в скобках.

Answer (score 3):

#### 64 символа

> кратко опишите изменения: орфография, пунктуация, форматирование

К черту скобки, они не нужны. Явно подходит двоеточие: есть обобщающее слово «изменения» и перечисляются разные типы изменений.

Comment: Шрифт кстати не моноширинный. Поэтому количество символов не совсем подходящий показать.

Comment: @alexolut согласен, что не точный — но приблизительно он подходит.

Comment: Можно еще добавить метку [соревнование] :)

Comment: @alexolut к вопросу-то? Ну да, этакий локализаторский гольф. )

Comment: Не в курсе, где строка с `etc` используется?

Comment: @alexolut неа, не видел. Возможно, старая версия.

Comment: Возможно, что `etc` убрали по той же причине, с которой мы бьёмся сейчас. А что если добавить ещё многоточие в предложенную версию?

Answer (score 3):

Что описание должно быть кратким, и так понятно из размеров поля для ввода. Давайте уберём лишнюю шелуху и оставим побудительный глагол:

> Добавьте описание изменений

Answer (score 2):

Например, такой вариант:

#### 73 символа

> кратко об изменениях (исправление орфографии, пунктуации, форматирования)

Comment: Различие ровно в один символ.

Comment: @Other по крайней мере помещается в строку.

Comment: По лезвию. Вдруг решат уменьшить поле на пару пикселей из-за мелких, косметических работ?

Comment: @Other предлагаю решать проблемы по мере поступления.

Comment: Верно, но смотреть одним глазком на будущее тоже, знаете ли, полезно бывает. Я не против Вашего предложения, пожалуй даже плюсую, но по лезвию...

Comment: @Other Вселенная расширяется, так что и поле ввода авось тоже пойдёт вширь :)

Comment: Конечно, подождём, всего-то миллиард лет нужно :)

Comment: Смысла стало больше, так как добавили про пкнутуацию. Хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без явного описания возможных действий:

#### 39 символов

> кратко опишите сделанные вами изменения

Comment: Отлично, куда лучше.

Comment: @Other можно так: `кртк опиш. сдел вам изм.`

Comment: На точках разоримся, не пойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

> кратко опишите изменения: исправление ошибок в орфографии, форматирование