# Уведомление о принятом варианте голосования на Мете

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, мета

В процессе улучшения сайта часто задаются вопросы, предполагающие голосование и выбор в итоге наиболее популярного варианта.

**Хотелось бы решить, каким образом в таком случае следует уведомлять сообщество о принятом результате и завершении голосования?**

Ведь задающий вопрос и утверждающий решение не всегда один и тот же человек. Более того, на некоторые вопросы иногда имеет смысл ставить красные модераторские метки, ну и наличие галочки на принятом ответе тоже не будет лишним. Таким образом, получается, что для уведомления о принятом ответе и окончании обсуждения, может потребоваться участие сразу нескольких человек:

- автора вопроса (поставить галочку)
- модератора (поставить красную метку)
- корректора переводов (утвердить перевод)
- менеджера сообщества (обновить базу переводов)

Имеется в виду не какое-то активное уведомление типа сообщения в списке входящих, а нечто такое, что будет на странице вопроса. Чтобы зашедший на неё сразу (максимально быстро) понял какое было принято решение и когда оно вступит в силу. Например, нужно ли писать новый ответ, или редактировать выбранный с максимальным количеством голосов и т.п.

Например, по недавнему [вопросу о подсказке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4698/176217) я принял ответ (поставил галочку) и добавил комментарий к этому ответу о проделанных действиях. Но в общем случае для этого нужно быть автором вопроса.

Comment: @AK и делать это в комментарии к какому-то случайно выбранному сообщению :)

Comment: Мне кажется, есть смысл уточнить, что вы понимаете под "сообществом". Только топикстартера, всех отметившихся в теме (комментарием или ответом) или вообще сообщество в целом (как говорят юристы -- "неограниченный круг лиц")?

Comment: @AK имеется в виду тот круг лиц, которые, попав на страницу вопроса, должны понять, что вопрос уже решен и решен определенным образом.

Comment: Не понимаю. Как вы их определяете, этот круг лиц? Это могу быть люди, которые не принимали участия в дискуссии? Если да -- то неограниченный круг лиц, бюллетень; если нет -- просите себе права модератора или уведомляйте ручками по старинке. PS Хочется всё услышать правило определения круга ЗЛ.

Comment: Вроде был уже такой вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а ответ у него был?

Comment: @alexolut  помню, что обсуждали проблему: решение на Мете принято, но в справке никак не отражено. Сходу не нашёл, вечером ещё погляжу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin в справке-то фиг с ним :) лишь бы ответ найти.

Answer (score 4):

Информирование сообщества (т.е. -- "неограниченного количества лиц") нужно делать через публикацию информационных сообщений.

Нужно выпускать на мете периодический бюллетень, в котором приводить дайджест сделанных изменений.

Образцы которые делал когда-то Николас см. по ссылкам:  [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497/) и [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3694/).

При этом желательно линковать их друг с другом (в новом давать ссылку на предыдущий), чтобы можно было переходить к более ранним.

Другие альтернативы (уведомлять *каждого* участника сообщества о изменениях, а не только отметившихся в теме) попахивают спамом (доставкой нежелательных уведомлений).

PS Пожалуй, с учётом комментария " имеется в виду тот круг лиц, которые, попав на страницу вопроса, должны понять, что вопрос уже решен и решен определенным образом" мой ответ уже не актуален и его можно удалить.

---

Ответ на поздние уточнения в вопросе.

Если есть необходимость делать уведомления без нотификации во входящих можно в вопросе постить плашки:

> Вопрос передан разработчикам Stack Exchange, ждём пока будет принято
>   решение по [этому вопросу](http://example.com)

или (с символами BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK и BALLOT BOX):

> ☑ выбрать вариант перевода

Очень много таких плашек любят повесить в вики-движках на базе mediawiki и по-моему это вполне удобный способ.

Конкретные плашки для разных случаев -- это уже нужно смотреть по обстоятельствам.

Вероятно, если нужно несколько плашек -- лучше подписывать плашку своим логином, чтобы было понятно, кто и что сделал/пишет.

> ☑ alexolut: к 23.12.2017 выбрать вариант перевода

Comment: Идея хорошая. Но, я думаю, имеет смысл ограничиваться имеющимися механизмами. Так как доработки движка в этом случае сомнительны. Только надо решить как их правильно скомпоновать.

Answer (score 1):

Идея сомнительная, но всё же. Можно закрывать вопрос (то есть блокировать возможность добавления новых ответов) с частной причиной и добавлением ссылки на ответ. Один (основной) из минусов - необходимо быть модератором. В принципе похожего эффекта можно добиться добавлением метки [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) и обязательного описания правки с указанием ссылки на принятый ответ. Но всё равно требуются модераторские полномочия, как ни крути.